# Django Logging: Logs not printed in order

Tags: python, django

We have a django application setup for a production,

Logging handlers are defined as

```
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
    },
},
```

Logs which are printed in our log file is not in order, some of them are incomplete and printed later after printing other logs.

Server is running on gunicorn(with 3 workers).

Is it because of workers running asynchronously ? Any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Each worker should write to its own log file (e.g., `debug.worker1.log`). You now have several processes competing to write to the same file which may mean things are not written in chronological order.

You should then use separate tools (e.g., Unix tools or logging aggregation tools) to either merge them or analyse them as needed.